While migrating Wcf project into CoreWcf .net8.0. How to use Wcf web.config setting into Corewcf projects?
Below is  is my wcf Web.config file code which i want to use in corewcf projects
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="HubBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
                    <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256Sha256Rsa15"/>
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Default"/>
                    <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_IProductServiceMahV20181" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
                    <security/>
                    <textMessageEncoding/>
                    <httpsTransport/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_IReportingServiceMahV20181">
                    <security/>
                    <textMessageEncoding/>
                    <httpsTransport/>
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="Behavior_M_1126_1_certification" name="VeriShieldProxy.Wcf.ProductService_M_1126_1_certification">
                <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="HubBinding" name="ProductService_M_1126_1_certification" contract="VeriShieldProxy.Wcf.IProductServiceMahV20181"/>
            </service>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="Behavior_M_1126_1_certification" name="VeriShieldProxy.Wcf.ReportingService_M_1126_1_certification">
                <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="HubBinding" name="ReportingService_M_1126_1_certification" contract="VeriShieldProxy.Wcf.IReportingServiceV20161"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Behavior_M_1126_1_certification">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="83796fd9d459e9ea7aa6360a411dcbe9e88dabcd" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
                    </serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" suppressAuditFailure="true"/>
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="Behavior_M_1126_2_production">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="c541f3975f595778c35c52f670d2940a7893efgh" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
                    </serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" suppressAuditFailure="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Tried below code in Program.cs file to use web.config setting into corewcf projects
Getting below error
enter image description here
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type 'VeriShieldProxy.Wcf.IProductServiceMahV20181' in assembly 'CoreWCF.ConfigurationManager, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=64a15a7b0fecbbfb'.'

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices();
builder.Services.AddServiceModelConfigurationManagerFile("Web.config");
builder.Services.AddServiceModelMetadata();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceBehavior, UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseServiceModel(serviceBuilder =>
{
    serviceBuilder.AddService<Service>();
    serviceBuilder.AddServiceEndpoint<Service, IService>(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), "/Service.svc");
    serviceBuilder.AddService<VeriShieldProxy.Wcf.ProductServiceV20181>();
    serviceBuilder.AddServiceEndpoint<VeriShieldProxy.Wcf.ProductServiceV20181, VeriShieldProxy.Wcf.IProductServiceV20181>(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), "/ProductServiceV20181.svc");
    var serviceMetadataBehavior = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
});

app.Run();


Many of the packages in the ASP.NET Framework are not available in ASP.NET Core. If there are some configurations in web.config that cannot be used by core, the default configuration is usually used or an error is reported. You can read this document.
